# EnumerateFiles in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] EnumerateFiles(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` error. I need to get links to images from folders, I get ID from the database.

```
        // Collect flat items and add in List<>
        var nearestItems = from item in _db.Flats
                           select new listItem()
                           {
                               Price = item.Price,
                               Address = item.Address,
                               Bathroom = item.Bathroom,
                               BesprovodnoiInternet = item.BesprovodnoiInternet,
                               City = item.City,
                               FloorAll = item.FloorAll,
                               FloorCurrent = item.FloorCurrent,
                               Funiture = item.Funiture,
                               Kondicioner = item.Kondicioner,
                               PartyFree = item.PartyFree,
                               RoomQuantity = item.RoomQuantity,
                               TipArendy = item.TipArendy,
                               TV = item.TV,
                               ImagesString = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Prop/" + item.FlatID + "/"))
                                               .Select(fn => "~/Content/Prop/" + item.FlatID + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToList()
                           };
```

Are there fix for this or alternate code?

Comment: Is there a single image or a  list of images?

Comment: Thank you Farhad Jabiyev and Hamlet Hakobyan! It works now! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query should be translated to SQL query to run on SQL Server. It is obvious that the engine cant translate `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to SQL query.
You can add new property `FlatId` to your `listItem` and try this:

```
// Collect flat items and add in List<>
var nearestItems = (from item in _db.Flats
                       select new listItem()
                       {
                           Price = item.Price,
                           Address = item.Address,
                           Bathroom = item.Bathroom,
                           BesprovodnoiInternet = item.BesprovodnoiInternet,
                           City = item.City,
                           FloorAll = item.FloorAll,
                           FloorCurrent = item.FloorCurrent,
                           Funiture = item.Funiture,
                           Kondicioner = item.Kondicioner,
                           PartyFree = item.PartyFree,
                           RoomQuantity = item.RoomQuantity,
                           TipArendy = item.TipArendy,
                           TV = item.TV,
                           FlatId = item.FlatID,
                       }).ToList();
foreach(var item in nearestItems)
{
    item.ImagesString = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Prop/" + item.FlatId + "/"))
     .Select(fn => "~/Content/Prop/" + item.FlatId + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to add get accessor for the `ImagesString` property.

Comment: To the `listItem` class implementation.

Comment: And you know that there is no one?

Comment: I can predict that, based on OP question. If you don't want to change your answer then don't. I just told my idea. It is permitted here, doesn't?

Comment: It is based on your opinion and we don't know use cases of that class. The example in the answer just shows the way to avoid issue.

Comment: I didn' told your answer is wrong. If you paid an attention!! I commented that  "*It would be better to add...*". So, there is nothing to argue.

Comment: Well, it is not a good idea to add the enumeration in the getter, unless you are going to cache the results as well, otherwise this can cause unnecessary disk I/O. Totally depends on what is the usage of the ImagesString list and how it should be affected if files were to be added after initial construction and the context where this ListItem is used.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I agree, OP must change some other thigns also to make the code better. For example OP can begin from property accessor. Then OP can change it to  method and store some values in private fields and so on...

Answer (score 0):

`EntityFramework` will build query based on your LINQ which will execute in the database. So there are some constarints while using LINQ to Entity. How must EF convert this code to the database query? `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

***There is no way.***

So, you must select only required properties and then change them as you wish in .net:

```
var nearestItems = (from item in _db.Flats
                       select new listItem()
                       {
                           Price = item.Price,
                           Address = item.Address,
                           Bathroom = item.Bathroom,
                           BesprovodnoiInternet = item.BesprovodnoiInternet,
                           City = item.City,
                           FloorAll = item.FloorAll,
                           FloorCurrent = item.FloorCurrent,
                           Funiture = item.Funiture,
                           Kondicioner = item.Kondicioner,
                           PartyFree = item.PartyFree,
                           RoomQuantity = item.RoomQuantity,
                           TipArendy = item.TipArendy,
                           TV = item.TV,
                           FlatId = item.FlatID,
                       }).ToList();
```

And in you class change the `get` accessor of your property `ImagesString`:

```
public List<string> ImagesString
{
    get 
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Prop/" + FlatID + "/"))
                        .Select(fn => "~/Content/Prop/" + FlatID + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
                        .ToList();
    }
}
```